# Intent activity class not working

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

hey guys so im having a problem when trying to run the emulator of my application on android studio. this is the error im getting:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.dre.appli/com.example.dre.appli_app.LoginActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.dre.appli/com.example.dre.appli_app.LoginActivity} does not exist.
```

ive tried everything that people have suggested to no avail. here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wheretas.appli_app">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".CreateAccount"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="app.createaccount" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: how can you have 2 activities as LAUNCHER?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `LoginActivity` has a package `com.example.dre.appli_app.LoginActivity`

But your manifest's package is different:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wheretas.appli_app">
...
```

Try to set it `com.example.dre.appli_app`

Comment: they all are set to the same package being com.example.dre.appli_app

Comment: try to remove a <intent-filter>...</intent-filter> block from your .CreateAccount activity.